Microsoft D365 OData Invalid URL with entity that has composite key
I'm attempting to use OData to retrieve and/or delete specific records in the BillOfMaterialsVersionsV4 entity.  The following defines the composite key:
<Key>
  <PropertyRef Name="dataAreaId" />
  <PropertyRef Name="ManufacturedItemNumber" />
  <PropertyRef Name="BOMId" />
  <PropertyRef Name="ProductionSiteId" />
  <PropertyRef Name="ProductConfigurationId" />
  <PropertyRef Name="ProductColorId" />
  <PropertyRef Name="ProductSizeId" />
  <PropertyRef Name="ProductStyleId" />
  <PropertyRef Name="ProductVersionId" />
  <PropertyRef Name="IsActive" />
  <PropertyRef Name="ValidFromDate" />
  <PropertyRef Name="FromQuantity" />
  <PropertyRef Name="SequenceId" />
</Key>

I can't seem to avoid "Invalid URL" errors.  This is one of the variations I've tried that seems to coincide with what I see most in other posts about the syntax for dealing with DateTimeOffsets (ValidFromDate):
(dataAreaId='nava',ManufacturedItemNumber='26849',BOMId='26849_V1',ProductionSiteId='Nava',ProductConfigurationId='',ProductColorId='',ProductSizeId='',ProductStyleId='',ProductVersionId='',IsActive='Yes',ValidFromDate=1900-01-01T12:00:00Z,FromQuantity=1,SequenceId=1)

My guess is that the issue is with the date as the other fields are strings or numbers, and those are very straight forward and have worked for other entities with this syntax.  But I've tried NULL, blank, with quotes, without quotes, casting to datetimeoffset'...' like in version 3, etc.
I've also tested $filter-ing on the date and other fields with the same syntax (replacing = with eq as per the documentation).  And the $filter works just fine.  But I can't delete an individual record with a $filter url to my knowledge...
I'm at a loss but it would be great to figure this out as that will give me the flexibility to clear collections out while testing migrations in test environments.

Did you try to escape the ":" in the datetimeoffset value?

Would I escape it with the \ character?  I tried that, and I get "No route data was found for this request"

Backslash was in my comment, but it must have not been rendered @SamXu
